# jQuery throttling and queuing of AJAX requests

Tags: jquery

I'm interacting with an API that allows one action per 5 seconds. However, I want to ensure all requests end up with the host. How can I queue and throttle the requests that are made against an API by using .ajax()?

Much obliged!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could do something along these lines

```
var requests = [];

setInterval(function() {
    if(requests.length > 0) {
        var request = requests.pop();
        if(typeof request === "function") {
            request();
        }
    }
}, 5000);

// then anywhere you need to make an ajax request
requests.push(function() {
    // ajax request here
    $.ajax({
        url: "/foo", // some variable from outer scope
        success: function(a,b,c) {
            // handle it
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: This is really good, but how do you prevent the first function in the queue from being throttled?

Answer (score 3):

jQuery has a [.delay()](http://api.jquery.com/delay/) and [.queue()](http://api.jquery.com/queue/) interface I suggest you checkout and read about.

Comment: delay() and queue() only apply to animations, which use the effects queue. They won't be helpful for delaying AJAX.

Comment: @Lamah Not true, `.delay()` and `.queue()` can be used for your own queues (or the default `fx` queue, which is used for animations). Any generic function can be added to an arbitrarily named queue.

Comment: You're quite right, clearly I need to learn how to read the documentation more closely!

Answer (score 1):

I would highly recommend this plugin for throttling Ajax requests: http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-throttle-debounce-plugin/

Comment: This doesn't ensure that all the requests actually get made - it just drops function calls if they are made too often.

Answer (score 1):

This is a shorter solution and doesn't throttle the first call put into the queue.

```
let ajaxQueue = [];
let ajaxQueueTime = 2000;
```

Execute your ajax calls like this.

```
requests.push(function() {
    $.get(url, function(rsp) {
        console.log("Hello");
    });
});
```

This is the routine that processes the ajax call queue.

```
(function throttleAjax() {
    if (ajaxQueue.length > 0) ajaxQueue.pop()();
    setTimeout(throttleAjax, ajaxQueueTime);
})();
```

Answer (score -4):

If you want to *ensure* anything then you'd best get a medium *other* than the internet - it is inherently unreliable. Anyway, in order to *try* to ensure, you could use the Javascript [`setTimeout`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp) method to initiate the call at a later time.

Other than that, if you don't want to use any other third party resources, you could look into the [`delay`](http://api.jquery.com/delay/) method exposed by jQuery.

Comment: This is an unsubstantiated opinion. Reliable data transmission over internet is mundane.