# Performance when ajax calls are being triggered by user

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, knockout.js

In my SPA web app I have a tree-like system in which users can navigate up and down using arrow buttons. Every time a new page is loaded an ajax call ($.getJSON) is triggered, fetching content for that page.

```js
load: function () {
            this.guidArray().forEach(function (currentGuid) {
                $.getJSON("/report/getdata", { guid: currentGuid }, function (data) {
                    var report = { title: data.name, fuid: currentGuid };
                    this.reports.push(report);
                }.bind(this))
                .success(function () { this.numberOfLoadedReports(this.numberOfLoadedReports() + 1); }.bind(this));
            }.bind(this));
        }
```

If a user is navigating quickly between pages there's an impact on performance, since all ajax calls in between are being triggered as well. What are some methods or patterns to cancel or in other way govern so that only the necessary calls are being made?

Comment: You've already mentioned it. *"What are some methods or patterns to **cancel** or "* Cancel the requests, that's the only option. Once a request has begun, all you can do to stop it is abort it. If you want to know *how* to abort it, that can be found in the documentation.

Comment: You can try add global variable and set it to TRUE in your success function and FALSE after ajax request (after $.getJSON...), and before calling the your load function check if this variable TRUE or FALSE

Comment: You could throttle/delay the requests.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7082527/jquery-throttling-and-queuing-of-ajax-requests

Answer (score 0):

You can try add global variable and set it to `TRUE` in your success function (and default also `TRUE`) and `FALSE` after ajax request (after `$.getJSON`...), and before calling the your load function check if this variable `TRUE` or `FALSE`
So, something like

```
var requestIsPossible = TRUE;
if(requestIsPossible){
load: function () {
            this.guidArray().forEach(function (currentGuid) {
                requestIsPossible = FALSE;
                $.getJSON("/report/getdata", { guid: currentGuid }, function (data) {
                    var report = { title: data.name, fuid: currentGuid };
                    this.reports.push(report);
                }.bind(this))
                .success(function () { 
                  requestIsPossible = TRUE;
                  this.numberOfLoadedReports(this.numberOfLoadedReports() + 1); }.bind(this));
            }.bind(this));
        }}
```