# Globally Rate Limit $.ajax requests in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Is there a way via `$.ajaxSetup` to throttle requests so anything after X requests in Y seconds don't happen until time has passed so throttling can reset itself? I know I could use [jquery throttle](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-throttle-debounce-plugin/),
But I am looking for a global way to effect all `$.ajax`, `$.get`, and `$.post`.

For example I might setup that I will only allow 20 requests in 5 seconds. On the 21st request I would have an error handler to display a message. Every 5 seconds the counter would start over so they can make requests again.

Comment: [Is this helpful?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7082527/jquery-throttling-and-queuing-of-ajax-requests) The accepted answer would seem to work in your instance only make the `setInterval()` function global.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a way to rateLimit all ajaxRequests. You can define a rate limit interval in MS and how many request are allowed in a given time period.

```
var RATE_LIMIT_IN_MS = 100;
var NUMBER_OF_REQUESTS_ALLOWED = 2;
var NUMBER_OF_REQUESTS = 0;

setInterval(function()
{ 
    NUMBER_OF_REQUESTS = 0;

}, RATE_LIMIT_IN_MS);

$.ajaxSetup ({
  beforeSend: function canSendAjaxRequest()
    {
        var can_send = NUMBER_OF_REQUESTS < NUMBER_OF_REQUESTS_ALLOWED;
        NUMBER_OF_REQUESTS++;
        return can_send;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Throttle one function, isSafe(), that returns true if it's good to go or false otherwise.
2. In ajaxSetup, have beforeSend() return the result of isSafe(). If it is false, the request will not be sent.

I haven't tested it, but it would be something like:

```
 const isSafe = $.throttle(numberOfMillis, () => true);

 $.ajaxSetup({
     beforeSend: isSafe
 });
```

Comment: Could you explain  () => true

Comment: That's just the concise ES6 arrow function syntax. If it has only one statement, you don't need to call return or include brackets. It's the same as writing function() { return true; }.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you put the ajax call into a function and track how often that function is called?

```
 var globalCount = 0;
    var ajaxOperations = {
        init: function(){
            //init
        },          
        loadNewsletterTemplate: function(templateDataFile){
            globalCount++;
            $.ajax({
                url: "data/" + templateDataFile,
                type: "GET",
                success: function(response){
                globalCount--;
                    formProcessing.convertToHTML_newsLetter_weeklyUpdates(response);
                    //console.log("response" + response);

                }       
            });                         
        }       
    }
```

Every time ajaxOperations is called you could iterate a global number and every time a success is performed you could do a retraction, thereby maintaining a steady flow. If (globalCount < 5) {call new ajax event}